# Traits and serialization/deserialization

Tags: scala, serialization, traits

Say I have two traits that I would like to mixin to a class. The traits each implement an abstract method that the class needs.

```
trait Writable {
    def serialize(out: java.io.DataOutput)
}

trait T1 extends Writable

trait A extends T1 {
   val aNum: Int
   abstract override def serialize(out: java.io.DataOutput) = {
       super.serialize(out)
       println("A serialize")
       out.writeInt(aNum)
   }

   def action = println("A action")
}

trait B extends T1 {
   val bNum: Int
   abstract override def serialize(out: java.io.DataOutput) = {
       super.serialize(out)
       println("B serialize")
       out.writeInt(bNum)
   }

   def action = println("B action")
}

abstract class M[CT1 <: T1](val mNum: Int) extends Writable {
   this: M[CT1] with T1 =>
   def serialize(out: java.io.DataOutput) = {
       println("M serialize")
       out.writeInt(mNum)
   }

   def action
}
```

I can then construct a concrete M with either A or B and serialize:

```
scala> val m1 = new M[A](10) with A { val aNum = 20 }
m1: M[A] with A = $anon$1@67c1e630

scala> val m2 = new M[B](20) with B { val bNum = 30 }
m2: M[B] with B = $anon$1@c36f58e

scala> val out = new java.io.DataOutputStream(new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream())
out: java.io.DataOutputStream = java.io.DataOutputStream@87afebf

scala> m1.serialize(out)
M serialize
A serialize

scala> m2.serialize(out)
M serialize
B serialize
```

Everything works as expected.  But how do I deserialize the objects while respecting the type of trait that is mixed into M?  I could output the trait's name in the serialize method and then have M's deserialize method dispatch on the name but what if I have classes other than M that A and B can be mixed into?  Then, each class would have to duplicate the behavior of M's dispatching deserialize.  The problem gets even worse if I have multiple traits that need to get mixed into an object to make it concrete and each has it's own custom serialization/deserialization to do.  Anyone tackle an issue like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, people have. The way to go is to use typeclass pattern championed by David MacIver's [sbinary](http://code.google.com/p/sbinary/) and Debasish Ghosh's [sjson](https://github.com/debasishg/sjson). Debasish's trilogy

- [Scala Implicits : Type Classes Here I Come](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/06/scala-implicits-type-classes-here-i.html)
- [Refactoring into Scala Type Classes](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/07/refactoring-into-scala-type-classes.html)
- [sjson: Now offers Type Class based JSON Serialization in Scala](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/07/sjson-now-offers-type-class-based-json.html)

are especially useful to all intermediate Scala programmers.

Today, many of the libraries are adopting this methodology including mine [scalaxb](http://scalaxb.org/). See

- [typeclass-based XML data binding](http://scalaxb.org/typeclass)

I've borrowed the naming idea from Scala Collections' `CanBuildFrom` and named my typeclasses as follows:

```
trait CanReadXML[A] {
  def reads(seq: scala.xml.NodeSeq): Either[String, A]
}

trait CanWriteXML[A] {
  def writes(obj: A, namespace: Option[String], elementLabel: Option[String],
      scope: NamespaceBinding, typeAttribute: Boolean): NodeSeq
}

trait XMLFormat[A] extends CanWriteXML[A] with CanReadXML[A]
```

**Edit**:

> Could you explain to me how the framework chooses between "with A" or "with B"?

Using the typeclass pattern, the libraries mixes in neither `A` nor `B`.
To take scalaxb for example, it provides a method called `scalaxb.fromXML` in the package object defined as follows:

```
def fromXML[A](seq: NodeSeq, stack: List[ElemName] = Nil)
              (implicit format: XMLFormat[A]): A = format.reads(seq, stack) match {
  case Right(a) => a
  case Left(a) => throw new ParserFailure(a)
}
```

Given that you have XML document, and you want to unmarshal (deserialize) it to `ipo.Address` object, you would call

```
scalaxb.fromXML[ipo.Address](<shipTo xmlns="http://www.example.com/IPO">
  <name>Foo</name>
  <street>1537 Paper Street</street>
  <city>Wilmington</city>
</shipTo>)
```

The `Address` object stays pure using the typeclass pattern:

```
case class Address(name: String, street: String, city: String)
```

How does the compiler know what to do? The magic is the implicit parameter required by `fromXML` called `implicit format: XMLFormat[A]`. This requires that you have `XMLFormat[Address]` available as an implicit value within the scope where `scalaxb.fromXML[ipo.Address](...)` is called.

This made available in the code generated by scalaxb because it mixes in `XMLProtocol` into the package object of `ipo` package. And `ipo.XMLProtocol` defines

```
implicit lazy val IpoAddressFormat: scalaxb.XMLFormat[ipo.Address] = new DefaultIpoAddressFormat {}
```

**Edit2**:

I think I am starting to understand the actual question. You have an object consisting of trait mixins, and you want to somehow "deserialize" the trait composition on other process.
As you wrote, you could include some tag for each traits, and load whatever you can.

Since I've written so far on typeclass pattern, let me continue with the approach. The neat thing about having serialization code *outside* of the object is that you could actually describe mixin combination of the object. Suppose there are traits

```
trait Foo { def foo: Int }
trait Bar { def bar: Int }
```

and you want to describe the mixin as `<obj><foo>1</foo><bar>2</bar></obj>`.
Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1121835) I whipped up.
I defined typeclass instance for `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Foo with Bar`, and called

```
Def.fromXML[Foo with Bar](<obj><foo>1</foo><bar>2</bar></obj>)
```

which returned

```
Right(FooWithBar(1, 2))
```

Comment: It is not clear to me how these libraries choose which trait to mixin to the class on deserialization. Could you explain to me how the framework chooses between "with A" or "with B"?

Comment: So trait A and trait B contain different implementations of an abstract method in class M. I have edited the question to reflect that fact. I am looking to compose an object with behavior defined in traits and to allow that object to be serialized and deserialized.  In other words the concrete M instance is not just a data class. It has specific behavior.

Comment: With deserialization/umarshaling you need to put the implementation outside of the class because the object doesn't exist yet. I've demonstrated a way of implementing this by using typeclass, but you could also do this using companion object if you like.

Comment: I suppose it is better described as declarative dependency injection rather than serialization. I am attempting to serialize a statistical model so that it can be transferred to remote nodes for parallel execution. As such, I need to specify its behavior as part of the serialized protocol.