# Noise free JSON format for sealed traits with Play 2.2 library

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I need to get a simple JSON serialization solution with minimum ceremony. So I was quite happy finding [this forthcoming Play 2.2 library](https://github.com/mandubian/play-json-alone). This works perfectly with plain case classes, e.g.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait Foo
case class Bar(i: Int) extends Foo
case class Baz(f: Float) extends Foo

implicit val barFmt = Json.format[Bar]
implicit val bazFmt = Json.format[Baz]
```

But the following fails:

```
implicit val fooFmt = Json.format[Foo]   // "No unapply function found"
```

**How would I set up the alleged missing extractor for `Foo`?**

Or would you recommend any other standalone library that handles my case more or less fully automatically? I don't care whether that is with macros at compile time or reflection at runtime, as long as it works out of the box.

Comment: Is there some code missing? Is the only thing defining `Foo` the `sealed trait Foo` line? What do you expect to happen, then? I suppose `Json.format` would work for regular classes if they have an `apply()` and `unapply()` method.

Comment: Play json, as well as lift json should be ok. You see, you are trying to get a format for a trait, but almost all libraries that provide transparent serialization are based on the case classes. Just use case classes and pattern matching and you should be fine.

Comment: I need to be able to serialize type classes. Therefore I need a format for a sealed trait which is extended by a number of case classes. Should be a fairly common scenario.

Comment: The automatic `Json.format` doesn't seem possible with traits, but you can write them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145432/play-2-1-json-serialization-for-traits ; also, I've stumbled across this question, which could be of interest for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891393/traits-and-serialization-deserialization

Comment: I recently wrote a JSON macro that generates jackson code for any object structure using compile time type information. The macro is able to generate a match statement for all subtypes of a sealed type through the reflection api `knownDirectSubclasses`, seen here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$ClassSymbol. I don't know of any other Json library that does this, yet...

Comment: @Andy do you mind to share that code?

Comment: If you can wait a week, I can see about getting it up on GitHub. Warning: It was written for our use case at work and not as generic library.

Comment: @Andy No problem. I have halfway written my own implementation right now. The `writer` already works, still some problems to fix with singleton objects in the `reader` part.

Comment: @0__, depending on your goals, maybe we can combine forces

Comment: Yes sure, [this is the project](https://github.com/Sciss/play-json-sealed) -- indeed, I would think that this should be pulled into play-json eventually.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a manual implementation of the `Foo` companion object:

```
implicit val barFmt = Json.format[Bar]
implicit val bazFmt = Json.format[Baz]

object Foo {
  def unapply(foo: Foo): Option[(String, JsValue)] = {
    val (prod: Product, sub) = foo match {
      case b: Bar => (b, Json.toJson(b)(barFmt))
      case b: Baz => (b, Json.toJson(b)(bazFmt))
    }
    Some(prod.productPrefix -> sub)
  }

  def apply(`class`: String, data: JsValue): Foo = {
    (`class` match {
      case "Bar" => Json.fromJson[Bar](data)(barFmt)
      case "Baz" => Json.fromJson[Baz](data)(bazFmt)
    }).get
  }
}
sealed trait Foo
case class Bar(i: Int  ) extends Foo
case class Baz(f: Float) extends Foo

implicit val fooFmt = Json.format[Foo]   // ça marche!
```

Verification:

```
val in: Foo = Bar(33)
val js  = Json.toJson(in)
println(Json.prettyPrint(js))

val out = Json.fromJson[Foo](js).getOrElse(sys.error("Oh no!"))
assert(in == out)
```

---

Alternatively the direct format definition:

```
implicit val fooFmt: Format[Foo] = new Format[Foo] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Foo] = json match {
    case JsObject(Seq(("class", JsString(name)), ("data", data))) =>
      name match {
        case "Bar"  => Json.fromJson[Bar](data)(barFmt)
        case "Baz"  => Json.fromJson[Baz](data)(bazFmt)
        case _      => JsError(s"Unknown class '$name'")
      }

    case _ => JsError(s"Unexpected JSON value $json")
  }

  def writes(foo: Foo): JsValue = {
    val (prod: Product, sub) = foo match {
      case b: Bar => (b, Json.toJson(b)(barFmt))
      case b: Baz => (b, Json.toJson(b)(bazFmt))
    }
    JsObject(Seq("class" -> JsString(prod.productPrefix), "data" -> sub))
  }
}
```

---

Now ideally I would like to automatically generate the `apply` and `unapply` methods. It seems I will need to use either reflection or dive into macros.

Comment: in my opinion the apply/unapply approach is pretty dangerous. If the json class name isn't exhausted (Malformed json) the get call will blow off and you'll have no json error logging of this.

Comment: This is the same issue I am having... however the sample code in the answer fails for me... is this still the preferred approach?

Comment: to me it's giving Error to this line `case "Bar"  => Json.fromJson[Bar](data)(barFmt)` because of mismatch to Actual : JsValue[Bar] and  Expected : JsValue[Foo]

Answer (score 26):

**AMENDED 2015-09-22**

The library [play-json-extra](https://github.com/aparo/play-json-extra/blob/master/doc/playjsonext.md) includes the [play-json-variants](https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-variants) strategy, but also the [play-json-extensions] strategy (flat string for case objects mixed with objects for case classes no extra $variant or $type unless needed). It also provides serializers and deserializers for  [macramé](https://github.com/ChrisNeveu/macrame) based enums.

**Previous answer**
There is now a library called [play-json-variants](https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-variants) which allows you to write :

```
implicit val format: Format[Foo] = Variants.format[Foo]
```

This will generate the corresponding formats automatically, it will also handle disambiguation of the following case by adding a $variant attribute (the equivalent of 0__ 's `class` attribute)

```
sealed trait Foo
case class Bar(x: Int) extends Foo
case class Baz(s: String) extends Foo
case class Bah(s: String) extends Foo
```

would generate

```
val bahJson = Json.obj("s" -> "hello", "$variant" -> "Bah") // This is a `Bah`
val bazJson = Json.obj("s" -> "bye", "$variant" -> "Baz") // This is a `Baz`
val barJson = Json.obj("x" -> "42", "$variant" -> "Bar") // And this is a `Bar`
```

Comment: Thanks for the new answer. I don't understand why the author basically rewrote what [I did](https://github.com/Sciss/play-json-sealed), but well… We're having the same trouble with `knownDirectSubclasses` not safely provided by the macro system (and confirmation that this will _not_ be fixed any time soon)

Comment: Most likely he didn't know about it ... just like me :)

Comment: you wouldn't know of a library which creates formats with default values for missing properties (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616677/defaults-for-missing-properties-in-play-2-json-formats for details)

Comment: you could put that as a feature request in my project. I wouldn't want to generate default values _always_, but I could imagine it to be an option, like `AutoFormat[Foo](defaults = true)`

Comment: I wouldn't want defaults generation all the time. Ideally there would be 2 sigs : 1 for defaulting all values which can be defaulted and a withDefault(key, value) that second one would ensure the keyname exists and the provided default value has the correct type. I started writing the feature request when I realized, I need this for "normal" case classes not only for sealed traits derived ones ...

Comment: `knownDirectSubclasses` is broken, see 16) @ http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/changelog211.html#changes-to-the-reflection-api

Comment: The play-json-extra link is broken.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon thanks for the report, I fixed the link. Unfortunately the rendered site is down (reset to an apache landing page) but the doc is available inside the repo

Answer (score 7):

**Play 2.7**

`sealed traits` are supported in `play-json`.

```
object Foo{
  implicit val format = Json.format[Foo]
}
```

**Play 2.6**

This can be done now elegantly with [play-json-derived-codecs](https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-derived-codecs)

Just add this:

```
object Foo{
    implicit val jsonFormat: OFormat[Foo] = derived.oformat[Foo]()
}
```

See here for the whole example: [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/lcaaYMB/0)

Answer (score 4):

A small fix for the previous answer by 0__ regarding the direct format definition - the reads method didn't work, and here is my refactor to it, to also become more idiomatic -

```
def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Foo] = {

  def from(name: String, data: JsObject): JsResult[Foo] = name match {
    case "Bar"  => Json.fromJson[Bar](data)(barFmt)
    case "Baz"  => Json.fromJson[Baz](data)(bazFmt)
    case _ => JsError(s"Unknown class '$name'")
  }

  for {
    name <- (json \ "class").validate[String]
    data <- (json \ "data").validate[JsObject]
    result <- from(name, data)
  } yield result
}
```