# Defaults for missing properties in play 2 JSON formats

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.2

I have an equivalent of the following model in play scala :

```
case class Foo(id:Int,value:String)
object Foo{
  import play.api.libs.json.Json
  implicit val fooFormats = Json.format[Foo]
}
```

For the following Foo instance

```
Foo(1, "foo")
```

I would get the following JSON document:

```
{"id":1, "value": "foo"}
```

This JSON is persisted and read from a datastore. Now my requirements have changed and I need to add a property to Foo. The property has a default value :

```
case class Foo(id:String,value:String, status:String="pending")
```

Writing to JSON is not a problem :

```
{"id":1, "value": "foo", "status":"pending"}
```

Reading from it however yields a JsError for missing the "/status" path.

How can I provide a default with the least possible noise ?

(ps: I have an answer which I will post below but I am not really satisfied with it and would upvote and accept any better option)

Comment: Hi Jean. I've been digging into this issue and found [this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3244). There doesn't seem to be any activity except talking around it. Have you found a more elegant solution than a transformer yet?

Comment: I am still using the transformers for now. Until I get enough time to look at how to write my own macros I think that's all I will be able to use :(

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Play 2.6+**

As per [@CanardMoussant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44888575/7898), starting with Play 2.6 the play-json macro has been improved and proposes multiple new features including using the default values as placeholders when deserializing :

```
implicit def jsonFormat = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Foo]
```

For play below 2.6 the best option remains using  one of the options below :

**play-json-extra**

I found out about a much better solution to most of the shortcomings I had with play-json including the one in the question:

[play-json-extra](https://github.com/aparo/play-json-extra/tree/master/doc) which uses [play-json-extensions] internally to solve the particular issue in this question.

It includes a macro which will automatically include the missing defaults in the serializer/deserializer, making refactors much less error prone !

```
import play.json.extra.Jsonx
implicit def jsonFormat = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[Foo]
```

there is more to the library you may want to check: [play-json-extra](https://github.com/aparo/play-json-extra/tree/master/doc)

**Json transformers**

My current solution is to create a JSON Transformer and combine it with the Reads generated by the macro. The transformer is generated by the following method:

```
object JsonExtensions{
  def withDefault[A](key:String, default:A)(implicit writes:Writes[A]) = __.json.update((__ \ key).json.copyFrom((__ \ key).json.pick orElse Reads.pure(Json.toJson(default))))
}
```

The format definition then becomes :

```
implicit val fooformats: Format[Foo] = new Format[Foo]{
  import JsonExtensions._
  val base = Json.format[Foo]
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Foo] = base.compose(withDefault("status","bidon")).reads(json)
  def writes(o: Foo): JsValue = base.writes(o)
}
```

and

```
Json.parse("""{"id":"1", "value":"foo"}""").validate[Foo]
```

will indeed generate an instance of Foo with the default value applied.

This has 2 major flaws in my opinion:

- The defaulter key name is in a string and won't get picked up by a refactoring
- The value of the default is duplicated and if changed at one place will need to be changed manually at the other

Comment: I have accepted my own answer for now and for questions with solutions  trying to answer the initial requirement, I have tried to explain why it didn't fit. If a better answer is proposed I will move the accepted answer accordingly.

Comment: In my case the field was always the same (`createdAt`). In that case the first flaw is slightly alleviated: https://gist.github.com/felipehummel/5569dd69038142ce3bb5

Comment: The link to play-json-extra is broken now

Comment: Indeed, I have updated the links to the root of the doc folder on github for now https://github.com/aparo/play-json-extra/tree/master/doc

Answer (score 21):

The cleanest approach that I've found is to use "or pure", e.g.,

```
...      
((JsPath \ "notes").read[String] or Reads.pure("")) and
((JsPath \ "title").read[String] or Reads.pure("")) and
...
```

This can be used in the normal implicit way when the default is a constant.  When it's dynamic, then you need to write a method to create the Reads, and then introduce it in-scope, a la

```
implicit val packageReader = makeJsonReads(jobId, url)
```

Comment: The code exemple implies that you write your mapping by hand, I prefer a way to enhance the macro based mapping with the proper defaults, especially for "larger" case classes. Appart from this, my own solution also uses Reads.pure in the json transformer to set the default value.

Comment: @Jean - Yes, I'm working with "dirty" json where the macro Reads is pretty useless - bad field names, additional processing required, etc.  I can see where, if you're in control of the JSON format and quality, using it would make a lot more sense.

Comment: this use case is pretty far from what I described in the initial question :)

Comment: This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 17):

An alternative solution is to use `formatNullable[T]` combined with `inmap` from `InvariantFunctor`.

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val fooFormats = 
  ((__ \ "id").format[Int] ~
   (__ \ "value").format[String] ~
   (__ \ "status").formatNullable[String].inmap[String](_.getOrElse("pending"), Some(_))
  )(Foo.apply, unlift(Foo.unapply))
```

Comment: I've taken this approach; it works and it's also cleaner than the currently accepted answer, but unfortunately it shares one of the drawbacks in that the types have to specified in two places (the case class and the reads definition).

Comment: The inmap approach is interesting, I will have to see if there is a practical way to use it which doesn't involve manually writing the whole mapping. In the case of Foo in this question it is easy but imagine foo has 15 attributes ...

Comment: Agree with @StevenBakhtiari - I have been using this approach and it is very useful, and not just for defaulting values, but also doing other operations on the value returned from JsPath.

Answer (score 7):

I think the official answer should now be to use the WithDefaultValues coming along Play Json 2.6:

```
implicit def jsonFormat = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Foo]
```

Edit:

It is important to note that the behavior differs from the play-json-extra library. For instance if you have a DateTime parameter that has a default value to DateTime.Now, then you will now get the startup time of the process - probably not what you want - whereas with play-json-extra you had the time of the creation from the JSON.

Comment: I also confirm that this works in Play 2.6, no need to add extra dependencies. I tried to add play-json-extra but I had some issues related to incompatibility in dependencies in sbt.

Answer (score 2):

I was just faced with the case where I wanted *all* JSON fields to be optional (i.e. optional on user side) but internally I want all fields to be non-optional with precisely defined default values in case the user does not specify a certain field. This should be similar to your use case.

I'm currently considering an approach which simply wraps the construction of `Foo` with fully optional arguments:

```
case class Foo(id: Int, value: String, status: String)

object FooBuilder {
  def apply(id: Option[Int], value: Option[String], status: Option[String]) = Foo(
    id     getOrElse 0, 
    value  getOrElse "nothing", 
    status getOrElse "pending"
  )
  val fooReader: Reads[Foo] = (
    (__ \ "id").readNullable[Int] and
    (__ \ "value").readNullable[String] and
    (__ \ "status").readNullable[String]
  )(FooBuilder.apply _)
}

implicit val fooReader = FooBuilder.fooReader
val foo = Json.parse("""{"id": 1, "value": "foo"}""")
              .validate[Foo]
              .get // returns Foo(1, "foo", "pending")
```

Unfortunately, it requires writing explicit `Reads[Foo]` and `Writes[Foo]`, which is probably what you wanted to avoid? One further drawback is that the default value will only be used if the key is missing or the value is `null`. However if the key contains a value of the wrong type, then again the whole validation returns a `ValidationError`.

Nesting such optional JSON structures is not a problem, for instance:

```
case class Bar(id1: Int, id2: Int)

object BarBuilder {
  def apply(id1: Option[Int], id2: Option[Int]) = Bar(
    id1     getOrElse 0, 
    id2     getOrElse 0 
  )
  val reader: Reads[Bar] = (
    (__ \ "id1").readNullable[Int] and
    (__ \ "id2").readNullable[Int]
  )(BarBuilder.apply _)
  val writer: Writes[Bar] = (
    (__ \ "id1").write[Int] and
    (__ \ "id2").write[Int]
  )(unlift(Bar.unapply))
}

case class Foo(id: Int, value: String, status: String, bar: Bar)

object FooBuilder {
  implicit val barReader = BarBuilder.reader
  implicit val barWriter = BarBuilder.writer
  def apply(id: Option[Int], value: Option[String], status: Option[String], bar: Option[Bar]) = Foo(
    id     getOrElse 0, 
    value  getOrElse "nothing", 
    status getOrElse "pending",
    bar    getOrElse BarBuilder.apply(None, None)
  )
  val reader: Reads[Foo] = (
    (__ \ "id").readNullable[Int] and
    (__ \ "value").readNullable[String] and
    (__ \ "status").readNullable[String] and
    (__ \ "bar").readNullable[Bar]
  )(FooBuilder.apply _)
  val writer: Writes[Foo] = (
    (__ \ "id").write[Int] and
    (__ \ "value").write[String] and
    (__ \ "status").write[String] and
    (__ \ "bar").write[Bar]
  )(unlift(Foo.unapply))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't satisfy the "least possible noise" requirement, but why not introduce the new parameter as an `Option[String]`?

```
case class Foo(id:String,value:String, status:Option[String] = Some("pending"))
```

When reading a `Foo` from an old client, you'll get a `None`, which I'd then handle (with a `getOrElse`) in your consumer code.

Or, if you don't like this, introduce an `BackwardsCompatibleFoo`:

```
case class BackwardsCompatibleFoo(id:String,value:String, status:Option[String] = "pending")
case class Foo(id:String,value:String, status: String = "pending")
```

and then turn that one into a `Foo` to work with further on, avoiding to have to deal with this kind of data gymnastics all along in the code.

Comment: The problem with option is that I then must map or get and generally use monadic operations to access a value which is _not_ optional, just defaulted. Using an option there would introduce a false signal as far as typing goes, just to match the library's current implementation.

Comment: True, but you mention that your requirements have changed, so from the perspective of the "client" (in this case, the datastore), that value is optional (it is a new version of the schema, so to speak). In this case I'd advocate either migrating the data in the store (setting the default value wherever it is missing), or have a mechanism that deals with graceful backwards-compatibility from data in the data-store

Comment: Exactly : I am trying to have a mechanism to gracefully handle backward compatibility with data in the store (or with clients which haven't updated either) by providing an acceptable default value. this way when I read then write my data back to the store it is automatically updated and my system doesn't explode for older clients. I obviously use Option when there are no sensible default values, but in many cases I can provide the default (as I do in the case class)

Answer (score 1):

You may define status as an Option

```
case class Foo(id:String, value:String, status: Option[String])
```

use JsPath like so:

```
(JsPath \ "gender").readNullable[String]
```

Comment: Except I don't want to have an option, I want to have a value, providing a default value if it is not provided. The semantics of Option[String] and String are definitely not the same.