# Play JSON Combinators orElse not working to Double field

Tags: json, playframework-2.2, scala-2.10

I have a:

```
case class Product( 
    id: Option[Int],
    name: String,
    measure: Int,
    qty: Double = 0
)
```

and implicit json `Reads` in the Controller:

```
implicit val productReads: Reads[Product] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[Int] and
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "measure").read[Int] and
  (JsPath \ "qty").read[Double].orElse(Reads.pure(0))
)(Product)
```

and here createProduct action:

```
def createProduct = DBAction(parse.json) { implicit rs =>
    rs.request.body.validate[Product].map { product =>
    Logger.info(s"createProduct product:$product")
    //...
    Ok(toJson(product))
  }.recoverTotal { errors =>
    BadRequest(errors.toString)
  }
}
```

So, the `qty` field has a default value `0`. If client has not sent this field, the parser needs to get a default value, but when I want try create a product, the following error appears:

```
JsError(List((/qty,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray()))))
```

Following JSON client sent:

```
{
    "measure": 1,
    "name": "meat"
}
```

Why?, Anybody know where my mistake is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried running this in the REPL using `play console`, and everything is working just fine. `orElse` works just fine with `Double`. Pasting in the following:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Product( 
    id: Option[Int],
    name: String,
    measure: Int,
    qty: Double = 0
)

implicit val productReads: Reads[Product] = (
   (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[Int] and
   (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
   (JsPath \ "measure").read[Int] and
  (JsPath \ "qty").read[Double].orElse(Reads.pure(0))
)(Product)

Json.parse("""{"measure": 1, "name": "meat"}""").validate[Product]
```

returns:

```
play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Product] = JsSuccess(Product(None,meat,1,0.0),)
```

It seems as though there's another `Reads[Product]` defined in the scope of `def createProduct` instead of the one you provided, otherwise it should be working. JSON macro perhaps?

Comment: ooh, you're absolutely right @LimbSoup, I checked the turn I remain old "implicit val productFormat = Json.format[Product]", thank you very much @LimbSoup!!!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the Play JSON library does not support default case class values. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616677/defaults-for-missing-properties-in-play-2-json-formats?rq=1).